# Could Fusion Tables ROWID values ever be reset?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm using Google Fusion Tables as a backend to an application, and I'd like to use ROWIDs to specify relationships across tables (basically Foreign Keys).

All I'm really looking for is an assurance from someone "in the know" that the ROWIDs will never be reset, like they might if you were to do a database migration with a different backend.  If that's the case then I can rely on them to be solid forever (which is a huge reason to use a hosted backend).  I'm assuming this is the case, but just wanted to double-check.

Answer (score 0):

ROWID is likely to be stable. But I would highly recommend using your own key instead, either one natural to the data or your own synthetic ID. That way you have complete control.

Comment: I appreciate that, and that would be my typical solution with a typical backend system, but one of my reasons for using Fusion Tables is to release control of my backend to Google and the user.  And I kind of trust Google to maintain an ID better than my own code...